# Rails Coffeescript select val

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, coffeescript

I am new to coffeescript. This is what I have:

View

```
<%= f.text_field :name, 
        data: {autocomplete_source: Client.limit(5).order(:name).map {|u| Hash[ id: u.id, label: u.name, name: u.name]}} %> 
<%= f.hidden_field :id %>
```

Coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#client_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#client_name').data('autocomplete-source')
    minLength: 2
    select: (event, ui) ->
      $("#client_id").val ui.item.id
```

URL

```
...client[name]=testname&client[id]=
```

I can't get the id in the hidden field.
Any idea?

Comment: Seriously, guys, we'll just gloss over the whole "using AR in a view and not even a simple call, but a full-blown query" thing?